# javascript limit on positive and negative number with delimiter comma based onkeyup and onkeypress

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, delimiter

Today i have problem in delimiting number for negative and positive number. For example, i have a textbox to insert my number and the result after write the number. Suddenly the number is separated with comma delimiter like this either the number is positive or negative

```
eg :  1000 -> 1,000
     -1000 -> -1,000
     -1000.12 -> -1,000.12
     -0.00001 -> -0.00001
```

How to achieve this using javascript, what i know is using onkeypress and onkeyup. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the best solution, but you can implement this according to your need.

```js
 

 var msg = document.getElementById('myInputBox'),
    numberPattern = /^[0-9]+$/;

msg.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    msg.value = getFormattedData(msg.value);
});

function checkNumeric(str) {
    return str.replace(/\,/g, '');
}
Number.prototype.format = function() {
    return this.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
};

function getFormattedData(num) {
 var i = checkNumeric(num),
     isNegative = checkNumeric(num) < 0,
        val;
        
    if (num.indexOf('.') > -1) {
        return num;
    }
    else if (num[num.length - 1] === ',') {
     return num;
    }
    else if(i.length < 3) {
      return i;
    }else {
     val = Number(i.replace(/[^\d]+/g, ''));
    }
    
    return (isNegative ? '-' : '') + val.format();
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id='myInputBox' value="" />
```

Comment: how about the comma behind the number ? do you mind to tell me too how they work @Sumit? thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: @faris-fajar please clarify your questions.

Comment: in the example, there are decimal number like -1000.12 to -1,000.12. but from the run code snippet that i have tried, it is accepting more than one dot '.'

Comment: @faris-fajar if the user add more than one dot then that is user's fault as decimal number accepts only one dot. In order to fix this issue all you need to do is to keep a check the number of times the dot occurring, in your case just accept one dot and if it occurs again then don't add. Have I clarified your doubts?